# Selenium: unable to click Facebook's like button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a list of posts (birthday wishes) I wanna put like to. Facebook displays them with one URL so I open it with Selenium, scroll down to show the posts (clicking on the "show more" div)

I have problems when I try to collect the like buttons and click them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

usr = ""
pwd = ""

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("url of birthday posts")

# or you can use Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
assert "Facebook" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.send_keys(usr)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

while True:
      try:
       scroll = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='u_0_9']/li[6]/a")))
      except TimeoutException:
     break
      scroll.click() 
buttons =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='Mi piace']")
for element in buttons:
    element.click()
```

It doesn't return any error, but it doesn't work either! 
If instead of pointing to /input[1] I go deeper and point to the a tag with the 'like' text it returns 'element not clickable'. Implicit waits didn't solve this problem.

Here's the HTML of the div with the like button, comment etc (probably more easily inspectable on Facebook itself):

```
<div><form rel="async" class="commentable_item" method="post" data-testid="feedback_form" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;]&quot;}" action="/ajax/ufi/modify.php" id="u_0_c" onsubmit="return window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)"><input type="hidden" name="charset_test" value="€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є"><input type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="AQGBrIHV7nty:AQEeHD-RcWyK" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="ft_ent_identifier" value="10209101309310163"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="data_only_response" value="1"><div class="_sa_ _5vsi _ca7"><div class="_37uu"><div data-reactroot=""><div class="_3399 _a7s clearfix"><div class="_524d"><div class="_42nr"><span><div class="_khz"><a aria-pressed="false" class="UFILikeLink _4x9- _4x9_ _48-k" data-testid="fb-ufi-likelink" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1"><!-- react-text: 8 -->Mi piace<!-- /react-text --></a><div class="_2r6l accessible_elem"><div class="_1oxj uiLayer hidden_elem" style="left: 194px; top: 319px;"><div class="_49v-"><div data-reactroot="" height="52" class="_1oxk"><div class="_iu-" aria-label="Reazioni" role="toolbar"><span aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Mi piace" class="_iuw" href="#" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="_39m" data-reaction="1"><div class="_39n"><i class="_3j7l _iuz"></i><div class="_d6l"><div class="_4sm1">Mi piace</div></div></div></div></span><span aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Love" class="_iuw" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1"><div class="_39m" data-reaction="2"><div class="_39n"><i class="_3j7m _iuz"></i><div class="_d6l"><div class="_4sm1">Love</div></div></div></div></span><span aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Ahah" class="_iuw" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1"><div class="_39m" data-reaction="4"><div class="_39n"><i class="_3j7o _iuz"></i><div class="_d6l"><div class="_4sm1">Ahah</div></div></div></div></span><span aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Wow" class="_iuw" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1"><div class="_39m" data-reaction="3"><div class="_39n"><i class="_3j7n _iuz"></i><div class="_d6l"><div class="_4sm1">Wow</div></div></div></div></span><span aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Sigh" class="_iuw" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1"><div class="_39m" data-reaction="7"><div class="_39n"><i class="_3j7r _iuz"></i><div class="_d6l"><div class="_4sm1">Sigh</div></div></div></div></span><span aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Grrr" class="_iuw" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1"><div class="_39m" data-reaction="8"><div class="_39n"><i class="_3j7q _iuz"></i><div class="_d6l"><div class="_4sm1">Grrr</div></div></div></div></span></div><div class="_41nt" style="height: 52px;"></div></div></div></div></div></div></span><span><a class="comment_link _5yxe" role="button" href="#" title="Lascia un commento" data-ft="{ &quot;tn&quot;: &quot;S&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: 24 }">Commenta</a></span></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="uiUfi UFIContainer _5pc9 _5vsj _5v9k" id="u_0_v"><div data-reactroot="" class="UFIList"><h6 class="accessible_elem">Commenti</h6><div></div><div id="addComment_10209101309310163" class="UFIRow _4oep UFIAddComment UFIAddCommentWithPhotoAttacher _4204 _2o9m" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;[&quot;}"><div class="UFIMentionsInputWrap UFIStickersEnabledInput clearfix" direction="left"><div class="_ohe lfloat"><div class="UFIReplyActorPhotoWrapper img _8o _8r UFIImageBlockImage"><img alt="Enrico Bergamini" class="img UFIActorImage _54ru img" src="https://scontent-mxp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ash2/v/t1.0-1/c0.3.100.100/p100x100/1901608_10203597124548984_73184209618736027_n.jpg?oh=c60782b3357d58eb0f66bed8c63c3510&amp;oe=5774B23F"></div></div><div class=""><div class="UFIImageBlockContent _42ef _8u"><div class="UFICommentContainer"><div class="UFIInputContainer"><div><div class="UFIAddCommentInput _1osb _1osc"><input class="_1osa mentionsHidden" name="add_comment_text"><!-- react-text: 16 -->Scrivi un commento...<!-- /react-text --></div></div><div class="UFICommentAttachmentButtons clearfix"><div class="_r1a UFIPhotoAttachLinkWrapper _m" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-alignh="center" data-tooltip-content="Allega una foto"><span class=" UFICommentPhotoIcon"><input type="file" accept="image/*" aria-label="Allega una foto" class="_n" name="file" title="Allega una foto"></span></div><a class="_r1a UFICommentStickerButton" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-alignh="center" data-tooltip-content="Invia un adesivo" href="#" id="js_8"><div tabindex="0" class="UFICommentStickerIcon"></div></a></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></form></div>
```

I'm no expert in programming and I feel like I'm not pointing at the right xpath where there's the event listener. How do I understand where to point for a clickable xpath (generally in DOM but also in this form)?

Comment: I also tried with: buttons =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='commentable_item']/div[1]")
    for element in buttons:
    driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('commentable_item').submit();");


But javascript returns "document...submit" not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to find and click buttons is injecting Javascript with the really comfortable Selenium's Javascript executor:

```
driver.execute_script("var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('UFILikeLink _4x9- _4x9_ _48-k');for(var i= 0;i<elems.length;i++){elems[i].click();}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like button on Facebook can be extracted as follows:

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".UFILikeLink._4x9-._4x9_._48-k")
```

To avoid disliking already liked posts you can use:

```
for x in range(0,len(like)):
    liked = like[x].get_attribute("data-testid")
    if liked == "fb-ufi-likelink":
        like[x].click()
```